# Python: Calculate Redundancy Rate of a List

Tags: python, list, redundancy

I am trying to gauge the redundancy rate of a list.

Let's assume:

```
L = [a, a, a, a] => redundancy rate = 1

L = [a, b, c, d] => redundancy rate = 0

L = [a, a, b, b] => redundancy rate = 0.5
```

I couldn't end up with a meaningful way to do so.

Comment: So how do you define the redundancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the output matches the values in the problem description, I'm not quite sure if this is a valid measure. Maybe `min` is better than `mean`.

```
import pandas as pd
l1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
l2= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
l3 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']

def f(l):
    s = pd.Series(l)
    ratio = s.value_counts() / len(l)
    redundantContent = s[s.duplicated(keep='first')]
    if not redundantContent.empty:
        return redundantContent.map(ratio).mean()
    else:
        return 0

print("redundancy rate of l1: {}".format(f(l1)))
print("redundancy rate of l2: {}".format(f(l2)))
print("redundancy rate of l3: {}".format(f(l3)))
```

Output

```
redundancy rate of l1: 1.0
redundancy rate of l2: 0
redundancy rate of l3: 0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Define redundancy as `1 - num_unique_elements / num_total_elements`. I assume that you mean that the redundancy of the list with repeats in never exactly 1. For example:

```
lsts = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
for lst in lsts:
    redundancy = 1 - len(set(lst)) / len(lst)
    print(redundancy)

# 0.75
# 0.5
# 0.0
```

Comment: I had no idea about `set`, that is a much cleaner way to do it.

Comment: The first list (with unique ones) should return 1 and not 0.75.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a program that matches the concept given and optimised it thanks to Timur Shtatland's comment. The one thing I will mention is that it gives a redundancy of `0.75` for your first test case, this is because only 75% of the list is redundant and it seems to be what you meant (but let me know if it's not).

```py
unique = []

for item in L:
    if item not in unique:
        unique.append(item)

redundancy = 1 - len(unique) / len(L)
```

EDIT: As seen in Timur's answer, it is be cleaner to use `set` to define unique instead of coding a `for` loop.